# Use REQUEST variable as dynamic upload location

Tags: upload, request, files

How can I use a request variable used in an upload form like this?

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry">
<input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="29">
<input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">
<input type="file" name="fields[useruploads]">
<input type="text" name="challenge_id">
...
```

The idea is to use the field "challenge_id" as dynamic upload location.

[image]

Is there a way to get this?

Comment: Try something like `challenges/{{ craft.request.getPost('challenge_id') }}/`? I'd also be wary of accepting untrusted front-end input like this that ends up on the file system.

Comment: @Brad Bell: it works - the hint hearby the field "... like {slug] or ..." is misleading, because I have done all my tries with one curly brace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That field accepts any valid Twig code, so something like this should work:

```
challenges/{{ craft.request.getPost('challenge_id') }}/
```

Fair warning, though... I'd also be wary of accepting untrusted front-end input like this that ends up on the file system.

Comment: This seems pretty dangerous, unless Craft automatically prevents users from writing to directories outside the install (i.e. a user in the front-end passing in `../../../usr/bin/` or something malicious)…

Comment: Craft does some bounds checking for situations like this, but I added the warning in my initial comment to the answer, too.